# find additive inverse of modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-field, group-theory

For a set to be called as a ring, it should have the following properties

1. closed
2. commutative
3. associative
4. Identity existence
5. Inverse existence

but how is Z7 a ring, as there aren't any inverse element for addition as -n is not an element of z7={0,1,2,3,4,5,6}

if there are additive inverse for z7 , how to find it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about mathematics with no connection to cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additive inverse of $x$ is defined to be the value $y$ such the group operation $x + y$ results in 0.

If we examine $\mathbb{Z}/7$, we find that every element there does have an additive inverse.  For example, for the element 2, we find the additive inverse to be 5, as $2 + 5 = 0$ (computed modulo 7).

You might be interested to learn that multiplicative inverses also exist for all elements other than 0; even though one might naïvely thing that 2 does not have an inverse (because 0.5 is not within $\mathbb{Z}/7$), we find that $2 \times 4 = 1$ (computed modulo 7), and so 4 is the multiplicative inverse of 2.